# Calculating the sum of even terms in a fibanocci series which is less than 4 million

Tags: python

I get the correct answer here:
Sum - 4613732
Time- 0.0

```
import time

def factorial():
        i=1
        j=2
        fac=[]
        final_list=[]
        fac.append(i)
        fac.append(j)
        z=i+j
        while(z<4000000):
                z=i+j
                fac.append(z)
                i=j
                j=z
        for n in fac:
                if(n%2==0):
                        final_list.append(n)
        return sum(final_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        start = time.clock()
        print "Sum is"+ " " + str(factorial())
        print "Time taken"
        print time.clock() - start
```

Just want to get some insight oh how I coded the logic in python. Is it fine or can it be done better(w.r.t coding standards etc)?

Comment: There is a separate website called, [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In my opinion almost every program can always be written in much more better way! Always!

Answer (score 0):

There's a really neat trick for this.

Here's the fibonacci numbers:

```
F_1 : 1
F_2 : 1
F_3 : 2
F_4 : 3
F_5 : 5
F_6 : 8
F_7 : 13
F_8 : 21
F_9 : 34
```

- The sequence is (odd, odd, even) repeat.
- The even number is the sum of the two odd ones by definition
- So the (sum of odd and even) = (sum off the odd) + (sum of the even) = 2 * (sum of the odd).
  So long as we're summing up to a value which an even value.

i.e.

```
1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 = 
1 + 1 + (1+1) + 3 + 5 + (3+5) + 13 +21 + (13 + 21) = 
2 * (1 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 13 + 21 )
```

Now the sum of the first N Fibonacci numbers is the N+2 th fibonaci number - 1

Continuing our sequence slightly we get 34, 55, 89, ...

So

```
1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 = 89 - 1
```

and so

```
1 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 13 + 21 = (89 - 1)/2 = 44.
```

This leads us to the following algorithm:

1. Find `N` and `F_N` such that `F_N <= M` but `F_{N+1} > M` . To do this we use a formula from wikipedia [image: Explicit fibonacci inversion formula]
2. if `F_N` is even our result is just `(F_{N+2}-1)/2`, note that `F_{N+2}` can be calculated in O(log(N)) time.
3. if `F_N` is odd we step back until we find an even one, (either one or two steps back).

   - if it was one step then our result is `(F_{N+1}-1)/2 + F_N`,
   - if it was two our result is `(F_N-1)/2 + F_{N-1} + F_N`

All these steps are doable in `log(N)` time.